# Cucumber/Capybara test fails when it should pass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

When I manually run the website, it doesn't show `Incorrect account ID, please try again` and logs in perfectly fine but when I try the same thing with Cucumber/Capybara tests, it fails for some reason. I even outputted the value it is enterring in the form and it seems to be the same id. Please help!

`login.feature` file

```
Feature:A user should be able to login

  To fill in all the credentials and then go to the landing page of the website

  Scenario:Fill the credentials and click login
    Given I am on the login page of the website
    When I enter my credentials and click the login button
    Then I should be directed to the landing page of the website
```

`my_steps.rb` file

```
Given(/^I am on the login page of the website$/) do
  visit root_path
end

When(/^I enter my credentials and click the login button$/) do
  within("div.row") do
    fill_in 'Account', with: 'a1757552'
    fill_in 'Password', with: 'adelaideuni'
  end
    click_button 'Login'
end

Then(/^I should be directed to the landing page of the website$/) do
  expect(page).to have_content 'IELTS'
end
```

**Terminal output:** (Printing the account id after `ggg_d:`)

```
  Scenario: Fill the credentials and click login                 # features/login.feature:5
    Given I am on the login page of the website                  # features/step_definitions/my_steps1.rb:1
    When I enter my credentials and click the login button       # features/step_definitions/my_steps1.rb:5
    Then I should be directed to the landing page of the website # features/step_definitions/my_steps1.rb:13
      expected to find text "IELTS" in "Course Advice Assistant\nHelping you choose courses!\nIncorrect account ID, please try again\nAccount\nPassword\nggg_d: a1757552" (RSpec::Expect
ations::ExpectationNotMetError)
      ./features/step_definitions/my_steps1.rb:14:in `/^I should be directed to the landing page of the website$/'
      features/login.feature:8:in `I should be directed to the landing page of the website'

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/login.feature:5 # Scenario: Fill the credentials and click login

1 scenario (1 failed)
3 steps (1 failed, 2 passed)
```

Comment: what if you try to log in without use of cucumber? just capybara. I think cucumber has nothing to do with the issue.

Comment: Not sure how to run capybara by itself. I just use cucumber to run the test i.e. I just enter `cucumber` in terminal to run the whole test. Anything else I should try?

Comment: Where are you actually setting up the account? Generally tests run against their own DB and you need to actually set up all the records needed

Comment: Oh thanks a lot! I thought it would use the existing database records. How do I setup records or more better, is there a tutorial for doing BDD / TDD - cucumber / capybara / rspec with Rails?